# How to generate ObjectID in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, objectid

How do I manually generate an ObjectID if I need to insert a document to a MongoDB?

Is it possible to do with shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible,

Enter mongo shell (type mongo in terminal) and over there simply write:

```
new ObjectId()
```

This will return you a new ObjectId as you wish

Comment: I have a an array of objects where I want to put unique ID, How can it be done using mongo shell ? `{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58825a290eb4d4271a54f188"),
  "name" : "Some kind of name",
  "vals" : {
        *"_id" : ObjectId(new ObjectId())*,
    "key" : "some value for some key"
  }
}`